# Red reclaimed victorian tiles (outdoor) crumbling after only 6 months

Tags: tile, patio

About 6 months ago we had red/blue reclaimed Victorian tiles laid in a checkerboard pattern outside the front of our house.  Red dust seems to be constantly coming off the red tiles, so that the grout looks pink, and it will even tread indoors.  Now on one of the tiles the smooth surface seems to have come away about the size of a 50p piece.

Does any one know what might be causing this (wrong bed? wrong grout? need treating?), these tile must be a hundred years old, and seemed in fine condition before laid.

Perhaps unrelated, but might be:  we frequently find a white salt-like deposit on the surface of the tiles - almost like you might expect after the snow melts in winter and the gritting salt is left behind.  There hasn't been any salt around, and so I don't know where this is coming from.  It brushes off by hand easily.

**Edit:**

I had an "expert" come and look at them, and he thinks the efflorescence and crumbling are not related.  He wonders if they are particularly soft, and are not sealed and so they are simply wearing away because of that.  He is also suspicious that the glaze/surface may have been missing on some of them when they were laid, and so we are simply just picking up on it now.  I had a couple that were left over from laying and they are ok, but not all the tiles may be identical.  He noted that not all the red tiles seem to have faired as badly as each other.

I also did manage to get hold of the person who laid them, and he is also planning a visit.  He thinks they probably need sealing.

Comment: Which country/climate? English, judging from the "50p"? Surely fairly northern, since you're familiar with road salt, but these tiles were laid during late winter?

Comment: Sorry yes, UK East Anglia - (gardening hardiness zone 8 if that helps!), laid March, so not quite 6 months ago.  No severe weather at the time.

Comment: Weather so far this summer has been alternating lots of rain, lots of hot sun (well hot for UK ~ 20-28C), so it has been wet and then dry many many times.  White marks usually appear quite some time after it has dried though. (i.e. they aren't left behind from the puddle)

Comment: OK, so that rules out any incompatibility issue between the soft tile and the grout under freezing conditions ("hard" mortar & grout - made with Portland cement - aren't compatible with soft tile or brick under freezing conditions, while "soft" mortar & grout - made with lime - are).

Comment: The tiles still seem to be set solid, and the grout is firm with no cracks showing.  It is literally just like they are eroding away!

Comment: The issue with hard/soft mortar/grout only exists in freezing conditions - the mortar/grout needs to be more porous than the tile/brick because it's sacrificial (it can freeze and crumble and be replaced easily, sparing the more valuable tile/brick). Hard tile/brick already has low porosity so it's not nearly so prone to spalling in freezing weather. It doesn't sound like you're likely to have had freezing weather since the tile was laid, though, so you're not seeing freeze-related spalling.

Comment: Having tried googling around the white powder, it sounds a lot like something called "efflorescence" (cf Wikipedia), but I am unsure if this is connected to the crumbling.

Comment: I was thinking it was efflorescence, which would just be from the grout, but definitely shouldn't be related to the crumbling. Efflorescence is only a minor nuisance, and it should stop when the grout is fully cured. It's seen very often in interior tiling jobs (walls, floors), especially within the first few days.

Comment: They're NOT cracking, right? That'd indicate poor bedding. They're just... crumbling, primarily on top, on the wear surface? And they're definitely reclaimed, so they've been in prior service for a long time? GEEZ I wish I had a good answer.

Comment: I've had a couple of other suggestions: one guy says maybe they need sealing, another is suggesting they should have been laid on a dpm. Any value to those ideas?

Comment: If this was a freeze-thaw problem, I'd (tentatively) agree, but neither seems appropriate for this - the clay body of the tiles SHOULD NOT be dissolving just from the presence of moisture. Of course, it should also NOT be wearing unless it's being attacked chemically. Which brings up a question: Have you used, or are you using, any sort of cleaning chemical on these tiles? Certain chemicals may attack the clay.

Comment: Not used any chemicals, but could there be chemicals in the mortar/base?  We don't know, chemically, what the salt is that is efflorescing.  Also they are all wearing evenly - i.e. not just the ones that are walked on, but the ones at the sides/corners just as much.  Also it is only the red ones.  The blue ones are unchanged.

Comment: Interesting - I suspect that the red clay gets its color from iron oxide, which may be attacked by acids. I'd THINK that the mortar would be a little basic (high PH) instead of acidic (low PH), but it's possible that it may be acidic. Are you in an area known to experience acid rain? Also... are these tiles glazed or unglazed?